# Visual Studio Code debug mode recognizes file path, but normal mode says "No such file or directory"?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In a Python script, I've got a filepath set up as follows:

```
train_dir = '../dataset/train'
```

If I run my code file using the VS Code debugger, the code runs fine and the file path is recognized and the files in it are read. However, if I run the same code without the debugger (by right clicking and hitting 'Run Python File in Terminal'), then I get a "Couldn't open file ([Errno 2] No such file or directory:" error (regarding a files in the directory).

What's going on here that the debugger recognizes the relative filepath, but just running it normally doesn't? Does the debugger start from the current working directory, but the right-click and running the code in Terminal option doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check what is the working directory in each invocation using this little snippet:

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath('.'))
```

It will probably give you the needed information.

Comment: Thanks! This helped figure out the issue that running in Debug mode and from the Integrated Terminal launch in two different directories. The Debug mode was automatically starting from the location of the code file, whereas the standard mode was starting from a set current working directory. I was able to replicate the Debug mode's starting directory (the same directory as the code file) by opening the folder with the code with VS Code's Explorer: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal